# 'onClick()' method isn't working properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I'm trying to create a multiple choice app that counts the number of correct and incorrect answers.

Everything renders good but the app isn't working properly:

1. User choice is not defining as the correct or incorrect answer.
2. Question isn't changing to the next one.

It seems like I've made a mistake in the `onClick()` method, please help to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

```
const questions = [
  {
   question: 'What is 8 X 2?',
   options: [5, 16, 12, 18],
   answer: 16 
  },
  {
   question: 'What is 18 / 3?',
   options: [6, 10, 7, 5],
   answer: 6 
  },
  {
   question: 'What is 3 X 2?',
   options: [5, 16, 6, 10],
   answer: 6 
  },
  {
   question: 'What is 5 X 0?',
   options: [0, 5, 10, 6],
   answer: 0 
  },
  {
   question: 'What is 11 X 11?',
   options: [121, 144, 112, 120],
   answer: 121 
  },
  {
   question: 'What is 12 X 6?',
   options: [68, 82, 72, 56],
   answer: 72 
  },
  {
   question: 'What is 89 X 2?',
   options: [186, 192, 178, 155],
   answer: 178 
  },
  {
   question: 'What is 56 / 2?',
   options: [18, 32, 26, 28],
   answer: 28 
  },
  {
   question: 'What is 8 X 3?',
   options: [32, 18, 24, 21],
   answer: 24 
  },
  {
   question: 'What is 9 X 8?',
   options: [81, 72, 64, 68],
   answer: 72 
  }
]

function Question(props){
  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className='question'>{props.question}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function Option(props){
  return (
    <div>
      <button className = 'option' type = 'button' onlick = {() => {props.onClick()} }>{props.option}</button>  
    </div>
  )
}

function Options(props){
  const options = props.options.map ((option) => <Option key = {option} option = {option} onClick = {() => {props.onClick(option)}} />);
  return (
    <div>
      {options}  
    </div>
  )
}

function AnswerResult(props){
  return (
    <div className = 'result'>
      <div className = 'countAnswers'>
        <span>Correct: {props.correctAnswers}</span>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div className = 'countAnswers'>
        <span>Incorrect: {props.incorrectAnswers}</span>
      </div> 
    </div>
  )
}

class TriviaApp extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      questions: questions,
      correctAnswers: 0,
      incorrectAnswers: 0,
      questionNumber: 0
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  isGameFinished(){
    return !this.state.questions[this.state.questionNumber];
  }

  handleClick(selectedOption){
    const questionInfo = this.state.questions[this.state.questionNumber];

    if (!this.isGameFinished()) {
      let sumCorrect = 0;
      let sumIncorrect = 0;
      if (selectedOption === questionInfo.answer) {
        sumCorrect++;
      } else {
        sumIncorrect++;
      }
      this.setState((prevState, props) => {
        return {
          questionNumber: prevState.questionNumber + 1,
          correctAnswers: prevState.correctAnswers + sumCorrect,
          incorrectAnswers: prevState.incorrectAnswers + sumIncorrect
        }
      });
    }
  }

  render(){
    let questionInfo;
    const gameIsActive = !this.isGameFinished();
    if (gameIsActive) {
      questionInfo = this.state.questions[this.state.questionNumber];
    } else {
      questionInfo = this.state.questions[this.state.questions.length - 1];
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <div className = 'game'>
          <Question question = {questionInfo.question} />
          <Options options = {questionInfo.options} onClick = {this.handleClick} />
        </div>
        <AnswerResult correctAnswers = {this.state.correctAnswers} incorrectAnswers = {this.state.incorrectAnswers} />
        {!gameIsActive && <div><span>Game is finished!</span></div>}
      </div>  
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <TriviaApp />,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Here is a link to my CodePen code:
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/leocete/pen/xmdzaa?editors=0010)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asked here are expected to be useful for future readers. If CodePen disappears for any reason, this question will become of no value. Put in short, please include the shortest code required to reproduce the problem in the question **itself**, and **not** a link to the code.

Comment: You `Option` component `onClick ` missing 'C'   :)

Comment: I think you are missing value in Option tag

`<Option key = {option} option = {option} onClick = {() => {props.onClick(option)}} />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a typo in `onclick`, it should be with camelcase `onClick`:

```
<button className = 'option' type = 'button' onClick = {() => {props.onClick()} }>{props.option}</button>
```

Comment: Sure? https://codepen.io/AStarusev/pen/VqbEWV?editors=0010 The code works for me.

Comment: it's a paradox =) - despite our pens are the same, my code isn't working
https://codepen.io/leocete/pen/xmdzaa?editors=0010

Comment: Not working for me either. I tried on Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Something weird, it didn't work for me too but when retyped your `onClick` word and it works again :)

Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xtwshqyd/).

Fiddle said `Unknown event handler property `onСlick`. It will be ignored.` so I think there was something with chars.